# Regex to search and retrive strings from a data

Tags: javascript, regex

i have following data.From this i have to retrieve only `@US2319,@US2315,@US2335,@US2314`
(no dulicate values)

```
/features/card_edit_text.feature:    @US2319
/features/card_edit_text.feature:    @US2319
/features/card_edit_text.feature:    @US2319
/features/card_edit_text.feature:    @US2319
/features/card_editor.feature:  @US2315
/features/card_editor.feature:  @US2315
/features/card_editor.feature:  @US2315

/features/send_feedback.feature:    @US2335
/features/support.feature:    @US2335
/features/card_list.feature:    @US2315
/features/card_list.feature:    @US2381
/features/card_list.feature:    @US2314
```

Using regular experssion can i have search based on `@US` and get the unique values `@US2319,@US2315,@US2335,@US2314???`

Comment: do you need regex for some text editor or specific programming language?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please, provide more information about your programming context/language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
(@\w+)(?![\s\S]*\1)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nIq9qDKZgk60XRwx)

Demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eE5hW9/1)

If you can enable the DOTALL mode, `[\s\S]` could be replaced by `.`. Without this mode enabled, `.` won't match new lines while `[\s\S]` will (any char that is a space or not a space).

Comment: it is not getting i tried ` var regex = /(@\S+)(?![\s\S]*\1)/;
      var matchs = regex.exec(stdout);
console.log(matchs)
`where stdout is the data

Comment: helllo how can i use this in javascript

Comment: @Psl You need to enabled the global flag. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xL9emfw/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use either a serie of pipe (e.g. `grep … | sort -u`) or an `awk`'s array. Note that solution differ by the presence of the `@`-sign.

### Pipes

```
grep -o '@.*' /tmp/data.txt | sort -u
```

#### Explaination

- `grep`:

  - `-o`: output only the string matching the pattern
  - `'@.*'`: pattern where a `@`-sign is followed by a series of any characters
- `sort`

  - `-u`: unique.

### Awk

```
awk -F '@' '/@/{ cp[$2]++ } END{for (i in cp) {print i}}' /tmp/data.txt
```

#### Explaination

- `-F '@'`: use `@` as field separator (2nd field will contain the postal code) ;
- `/@/{ cp[$2]++ }`: for lines with a `@`-sign, add postal code as key to the `cp` array and increment its value ;
- `END{ for (i in cp) {print i} }'`: once we read all lines, we loop on the `cp` array to print each key (which are your cp code).

Comment: @Psl that's was just the skeleton of the pipe, I updated my answer to add a full blown solution

Answer (score 1):

You may use shell commands: `awk`, `sort`, `uniq`.